# Why Deep link doesn't working in Android, chrome version 114?

Tags: javascript, android, html, reactjs, google-chrome

We have a react application with iframe. Inside the iframe we have a button that should trigger an application.
It's working fine in iOS, and in android it's working on all chrome version except chrome 114.

We tried many option to trigger the app:

```
1. window.parent.location.href = LINK;

2. window.top.location.href = LINK;

3. window.parent.location.replace(LINK);

4. window.parent.location.assign(LINK);

5. window.opener.location.href = LINK;

6. window.event.returnValue = false;
window.parent.location.href = LINK
```

We tried all those options also in simple html and javascript project.

The only one option that was partially working was:

```
window.location.href = LINK;
```

Without the "parent", but the problem is that link was opened inside the iframe, but the application has been triggered.

Any help please?

Thanks in advance!